# Confusion between instance and class methods

Tags: objective-c

not sure if to use a class method or instance method to create NSarray.... i mean there are alots of ways of creating them...
Sorry new to ios development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically three ways to get, eg, an NSArray:

1. The standard alloc/init.  Conceptually, at least, `[NSArray alloc]` is a call on a class method of NSArray, and then the resulting object invokes a special form of instance method for the `init..` step.
2. `[NSArray arrayWithSomethingOrAnother..]`.  This invokes a class method on NSAArray which internally does the alloc/init (with a few twists) and then "fills in" the object as required.
3. `[someObject arrayByDoingSomething..]`.  This is a instance method on some object (which may or may not be an NSArray object) which returns an NSArray.

There actually aren't too many cases where there's overlap between (2) and (3) -- can't think of any offhand for NSArray, though there's a handful for the similar NSString functions.  And while purists may prefer the old alloc/init vs the `arrayWith...` class methods, there's not really much real need to use alloc/init on NSArray in the ARC environment (though it still has its place in the manual ref count environment).

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference if you are using ARC. For example these 2 lines return the same thing:

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:myObject];

[NSArray arrayWithObject:myObject];
```

The only difference is that the latter returns an autoreleased object, which has to be handled the same way as the other one if you are using ARC. If not, you should add `retain` to the second line of code, in case you want ownership of the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

You create NSArray or string the way you create in any programming language, i.e allocate memory --> initialize the instance variable to some state you want.

you can create array for e.g..

NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

Now you could have used some other class method also, let us take NSString for e.g..
NSString *myString = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%@ - this is my string -%@",@"<--",@"-->"];

Now using ARC, it do not makes much of a difference, as ARC will take care of releasing the object created as class methods generally are autoreleased.